# Actionscript 3 ByteArray XOR?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, arrays, bit-manipulation, xor

I've looked around and couldn't find XOR functionality for ByteArrays in Actionscript 3.
Can someone help me implement it (perhaps in the form of a function) while keeping compatibility with PHP's XOR?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    private function XOR(binaryData1:ByteArray, binaryData2:ByteArray):void{
        for(var i:Number=0;i<binaryData1.length;i++){
            binaryData1[i]=binaryData1[i]^binaryData2[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: This of course implies that either binaryData1 equals binaryData2 or binaryData1.length <= binaryData2.length